# How to cancel long running message handler in NServiceBus

Tags: multithreading, process, backgroundworker, nservicebus, msmq

I have long running message handler, so I need to have option to cancel it. I need to know whether NServiceBus provides any means to do this by design.

What is alternative solution can be?

Comment: Are you talking about a handler that doesn't quit and kind of hangs? Or are you talking about Sagas?

Comment: My situation is long running transnational batch operations, so if I cancel it, I need to roll back everything, so I cannot split that batch into small messages for processing, but  i need to have ability to cancel it.
So I was thinking to use Saga Data to raise flag in Cancel Message Handler and then read it periodically in Data Import Message Handler and cancel batch if needed.

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus, **despite being awesome in many ways**, doesn't offer you any built-in way to cancel message handling in the same sense as a background task runner would.

However, you could call into something like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) from your handler, which does provide this kind of offline task management. Even though it's been designed for use in IIS, it can be hosted in another container, such as a [windows service](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-windows-service.html).

As an edit to this answer, I have since discovered that hangfire doesn't actually allow you to cancel jobs which have been started, at least not in a tidy way. You can delete jobs which are in-process, but this does not have a cancellation semantic, as the hangfire server does not process further jobs on the queue in certain circumstance (like if you're running single threaded).

Comment: I don't know who put negative mark to this reply, I am as author of this question consider it as really relevant. It is more relevant than answer provided by Particular NServiceBus  support team. So I am really frustrated that commercial technical support team trying to shut up person who gives relevant answers.

Comment: @AE - huh. Probably the way I worded it. I have updated my answer to make it a bit less critical.

Comment: @AE you should post the Particular support you received for completeness.

Comment: I'm in an email conversation with @a-e about the issue. Normally we reply on Stackoverflow so that everyone can benefit, but for various reasons the conversation has been via email this time. Once I'm clear of what is wanted and what the proper solution is, I'll post a definitive answer here as well.

And I do hope people with downvotes aren't doing that because you're proposing something else than NServiceBus. :-)